# @Register directive in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, web-parts

I use the following directive in my aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="myWebParts._Default" %>
<%@ Register Namespace="myWebParts" TagPrefix="myWebParts_tag" %>
```

And my page has code snippet like this:

```
        <ZoneTemplate>
          <myWebParts_tag:HelloWorldWebPart runat="server" ID="_wp1" />
        </ZoneTemplate>
```

But I got the following error:

> Parser Error  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag
>   'myWebParts_tag:HelloWorldWebPart'.

What's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your register directive is missing either an `assembly` or a `src` information.

- If you want to reference a whole namespace of controls in another assembly, add the assembly name with `assembly="AssemblyName"`.
- If you want to add a single user control in the current assembly, add the location via `src="LocationOfUserControl.ascx`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for more info on the @Register directive.

Comment: Thanks, atticae. Your answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

It is solved by adding this:

```
  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="myWebParts_tag" namespace="myWebParts" assembly="myWebParts"/>
    </controls>
  </pages>
```